# Assistance with recipes for Dialogflow?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm completely new to using Dialogflow. What I'd like to do is get the user to type something like "search for recipes with broccoli leaves" (as i'm trying to promote zero-waste recipes) and then for the bot to output a recipe. any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: It is very difficult to answer such an open-ended question without having some idea of what you have read and researched so far and what questions you have about what you've read or tried. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I think your best course of action if you are new to actions on google is to take a look at some of their code samples they post of github and get an "idea" of what is possible with it. Usually this is the best starting point and then you can work from there. This is how I've started a lot of my projects.

As for answering your question for searching recipes, there's MANY ways you could go about this. You could basically set up intents that have the recipes ready. So for example, maybe if you had a intent that handled "broccoli recipes" you could set up an training phrases like:

```
What is a good recipe for broccoli?
Search a recipe with broccoli
```

And in your answers, you could have some recipes that you have put. A long solution, but still an option.

I'm not sure how experienced you are with web development, but you could set up a webhook with an external API for recipes that returns info about that stuff.

There's LOTS of avenues you could go. This was a broad take but dialogflow is a pretty broad topic in general!

Hope this helped!

Here's the [link](https://github.com/actions-on-google/) for webhooks